# How to locate the position of a block of text in a text document

Tags: python, text, find

My goal is to find the position of `text2` in `text1` in the example below:

```
>>> text1='young lady  and lived in a firm so outside the cathedral close  it was somberly furnished  and full of dark young portraits'
>>> text2='the cathedral close it was sombrely furnished and full of dark'
>>> findtext2=text1.find(text2)
>>> findtext2
    -1
```

Output: `-1`... which implies that `text2` cannot be found in `text1`.

Ideal output: `42`

Any ideas on how to go about this?

Comment: `"sombrely" != "somberly"`. Also, there are some double spaces in `text1`. Otherwise, your method is correct.

Comment: You have an additional space between 'close' and 'it' in the phrase portion 'close  it was' and also between 'furnished' and the following 'and' is this correct?

Comment: Thanks for observing the errors the text. I was just wondering where I made some errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the right method, `find`. Just that "sombrely" is not spelt correctly in `text1` or vice-versa (whichever you think works for you). Also check for space mismatches in both `text1` and `text2`.

Comment: is there a way to fix this without manually correcting the text? My data is just too big, you can't fix them all.

Comment: @Tiger1 I can't think of any. What's the purpose of fixing it? Don't you want the result to be correct? (unless you are copy pasting text).

Comment: I'm working on detecting duplicates, and part of the process is to correct minor errors and ensure proper alignment.

Comment: You cannot do that with a simple script. If you just want to find duplicates it's possible, but you cannot correct errors like the one in the question.

Comment: @Tiger1: if you know the range and tolerances of spelling mistookes then a regular expression might help.  The `match` object contains an `spos` giving the start position.  Another possibility is to create a dictionary of words with acceptable alternatives.  Non-trivial.